# Удаление прочих свойств JVM на WebSphere

Tags: jvm, websphere, jython

Пытаюсь удалить прочее свойство JVM на WebSphere

```
server = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + AdminControl.getCell() + '/Node:' + AdminControl.getNode() + '/Server:server1/')
jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', server)
props = AdminConfig.showAttribute(jvm, 'systemProperties').splitlines()
for prop in props:
 if AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name') == 'HttpSessionIdReuse': 
   AdminConfig.remove(prop)
AdminConfig.save()
```

Выдаёт WASX7017E: При выполнении файла "C:\data\command.py" возникла исключительная ситуация; информация об исключительной ситуации: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7077E: Неполный ИД конфигурации: в "[com.ibm.security.jgss.debug(cells/BASTIONNode01Cell/nodes/BASTIONNode01/servers/server1|server.xml#Property_1) com.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug(cells/BASTIONNode01Cell/nodes/BASTIONNode01/servers/server1|server.xml#Property_2) HttpSessionIdReuse(cells/BASTIONNode01Cell/nodes/BASTIONNode01/servers/server1|server.xml#Property_1524052228829) HttpSessionIdReuse(cells/BASTIONNode01Cell/nodes/BASTIONNode01/servers/server1|server.xml#Property_1524058949911)]" отсутствует закрывающая скобка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', visibleLevelId)
props = AdminConfig.showAttribute(jvm, 'systemProperties')
props = props.replace('[','')
props = props.replace(']','')
props = props.split(' ')
for prop in props:
    if AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name') == 'HttpSessionIdReuse':
        AdminConfig.remove(prop)
AdminConfig.save()
```